# IOError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python-imaging-library

Can anyone tell why PIL can't open this PNG file?

https://b75094855c6274df1cf8559f089f485661ae1156.googledrive.com/host/0B56ak7W-HmqAX005c3g5eTlBakE/8.png

I get IOError: cannot identify image file, and by looking at the code, it seems it tries PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile and corresponding "accept" function, and it returns False

I'm using version 1.1.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what the problem is with PIL 1.1.6 but I just tested it with the latest Pillow 2.4.0 and this worked:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open("8.png")
>>> im.show()
```

PIL in unmaintained and Pillow is an actively maintained and developed fork. To use Pillow, first uninstall PIL, then install Pillow.

Further installation instructions here: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: `uninstall PIL, then install PIL`: Do you mean install Pillow?

Comment: I'm on the hunt for a solution to the same problem.  So far Pillow's not helping.  Thankful for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

try to import cv2

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> import cv2
>>> im = cv2.imread("8.png")
>>> im = cv2.imwrite("8.png")
```

i hope its working...