# How do I retrieve all of the raw rgb data in .txt format (eg. 255, 255, 255) from a set of images (.png, .jpg, .bmp, etc.)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner programmer with a limited knowledge of Python, but I'd be willing to use any language if it's any easier for you.

I'd like to get this information so I can find certain rgb values in a large quantity of images.

If there is a more traditional way of doing this that you know of, such as in some sort of graphics editing program, that would be cool, too.

**EDIT:** when I say '(.png, .jpg, .bmp, etc.)', I don't mean that the images are a variety of different types. I just mean that I could use any one of these as a starting point.

Comment: why do you want text files? What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pillow to read images and numpy to write text files:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open(filename)
data = np.asarray(im, dtype=np.uint8)
np.savetxt(out_filename, data.ravel(), fmt='%i')
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly -- question is now solved.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have an image file already, you can use Pillow (or PIL) to load the image like so:

```
from PIL import Image

file = open('path/to/image.png', 'r')
content = file.read()
im = Image.open(content)
pixels = im.load()

for i in xrange(im.width):
    for j in xrange(im.height):
        print '({i}, {j}): {pixel}'.format(i=i, j=j, pixel=pixels[i, j])
```

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded Pillow and rolled back to Python 2.7 in order to make use of it. I tried the code and it returned IOError: cannot identify image file. Extra help, please?

Comment: Try with a simple PNG file first, see if that works. PIL sometimes requires libraries installed in the OS to be able to decode the image correctly. How are you opening the file?

Comment: I started by typing in imagefile = open("Test_Picture.png","r"), then I edited line 4 of your code to instead read file = StringIO(imagefile.read()). No doubt extreme beginner mistakes in there.

Comment: I've made some corrections to the code, check it now. You need to load the file into a StringIO object before you instantiate an Image object. I can see that's already what you've done though -- where do you get the error?

Comment: Still doesn't like it with same error. I used your code exactly with the substitution of 'path/to/image.png' for 'C:/Users/person/Documents/picturegallery/Test_Picture.png'. The error is line 6: im = Image.open(file)

Comment: You certainly don't have to use a `StringIO` object with the contents of the image file as filename.

Comment: BlackJack -- you're correct, no need for StringIO. However, the rest of the code should work. OP -- the issue could be related to your version of PIL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420817/ioerror-cannot-identify-image-file

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I had success using Daniel's method, but I'll make sure to look into more of pillow's capabilities in the future.