# IOError: cannot identify image file in Python

Tags: python, image

I am trying to run this start up code where I am trying to get python to read photos as I am trying to get it to copy all the photos in 1200 folders and paste them to a single photo for my deep learning project. But I keep getting this error or problem.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("1.jpg")
im.show()
```

This is what I get when I try to run the code.

```
anthony@anthony-G53JW:~/design4$ python copy2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copy2.py", line 2, in <module>
    im = Image.open("1.jpg")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2289, in open
    preinit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 365, in preinit
    from PIL import JpegImagePlugin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 40, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFile, TiffImagePlugin, _binary
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 50, in <module>
    from fractions import Fraction
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fractions.py", line 7, in <module>
    from decimal import Decimal
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 139, in <module>
    import copy as _copy
  File "/home/anthony/design4/copy.py", line 25, in <module>
    dataset = Image.open("1.jpg")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2317, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file '1.jpg'
```

Comment: Try converting your JPEG image into some other format. It seems that Pillow doesn't support JPEG out of the box, but it requires external libraries, such as `libjpeg`, as [explained here](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/installation.html).

Comment: so i tried to change it to png but i still get this


anthony@anthony-G53JW:~/design4$ python copy2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copy2.py", line 2, in <module>
    im = Image.open("1.bng")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2280, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.bng'

Comment: Did you type PNG or BNG?

Comment: my bad i changed it to PNG and still same error

Comment: but the last line is JPG?
i dont know why

IOError: cannot identify image file '1.jpg'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOError: cannot identify image file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420817/ioerror-cannot-identify-image-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=IOError%3A+cannot+identify+image+file).